# Delay the onPause() method

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application, and I was wondering if it is possible to delay the `onPause()` method until it receives a string from another Activity.

Comment: I think you would do better to ask the bigger question: how do I do x, instead of asking "How do I do x, by doing y" when doing y is probably not the right way.

Answer (score 4):

This would be a bad idea. If `onPause()` is delayed, then you're activity is likely to trigger an "application not responding" (ANR) error. You don't need to worry about a response from another activity being lost if your activity is paused (say, by the user pressing the HOME button); the system will deliver the response when the activity is running again.